# Separate contents from database and populate dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have values in database which is like `GGN-JPR-AMD` and so on...

What I have to do is populate 3 dropdown lists, each having one separate value like dropdown 1 must consist `GGN`, second dropdown should contain `JPR` and third dropdown should contain `AMD` or it should populate automatically based on the value from database..

please help

Comment: You mean a single column in the database table contains the entire value "GGN-JPR-AMD" and then there are more rows with similar 3-chunks values?

Comment: No
there are no three other rows consisting of these values...
all I have to do is seperate Names from `-` and post the values to dropown accordingly

Comment: Just get the column value, using string.split('-') split by -, and assign to respective dropdowns

Comment: You misunderstood what I was asking. Can you plz post your table structure here?

Comment: @HarshShah you can certainly use the `Split()` and create list and bind that to the dropdown control

Comment: Post your code to know better your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you want to split a value in a column into three parts,then set them to different droplists? if that, you can use Split('-') to do that, then your original value will be splitted into three parts in a string[]. but even more, I suggest that you could modify your database structure, after you solve this problem as this, you will meet other problems caused by it.